# If a woman had an aborted pregnancy, is the next son born considered, halachically, a bechor?

Tags: halacha, pregnancy-birth, bechor-firstborn

Does the halachic definition of "bechor" specifically apply to a full birth or a fetus?

Thus, if a woman aborted her first pregnancy, and the 2nd pregnancy produces a male birth, is that boy considered a "bechor" halachically regarding:

- receieving double portion of inheritance
- requirement to receive a *pidyon haben*
- fasting on Erev Pesach

sources, please